# How to feed Dynamic Populate Extender with data from asp:TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

The DynamicPopulate ASP.Net extension accepts the ContextKey as a parameter for the web service, but how do I assign that from an asp:TextBox?

I have tried code from http://www.aspnetajaxtutorials.com/2009/12/dynamic-populate-extender-example-ajax.html but that only work on a regular Html Text box, and not an asp:TextBox

Code so far:

```
<asp:TextBox
    ID="tbxWorkOrderNumber" runat="server" width="290px" MaxLength="100"
    CausesValidation="True">
</asp:TextBox> 

<asp:Label ID="lblPartNumber" runat="server" Text="N/A"></asp:Label>
<asp:DynamicPopulateExtender ID="lblPartNumber_DynamicPopulateExtender"
     runat="server" Enabled="True" PopulateTriggerControlID="tbxWorkOrderNumber"
     TargetControlID="lblPartNumber" ServicePath="HSRecordingWebService.asmx"
     ServiceMethod="GetPartNumber">
</asp:DynamicPopulateExtender>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to get this to work as originally intended.  Instead, I was able to use the [ASP.NET UpdatePanel Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398864.aspx) and some code behind to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your page load in your page's code behind:

```
DynamicPopulateExtender.PopulateTriggerControlID =  tbxWorkOrderNumber.ClientID
```

If this just works for a HTML input control, perhaps it expects the html ID. ASP.NET changes the ID when the textbox is rendered.